# Hoogle and yesod - how to easily find functions in non-default packages

Tags: haskell, terminal, yesod, ghci, hoogle

I installed hoogle, using `stack install hoogle`. Now I can search for functions using a command like this from `stack ghci`:

```
:!hoogle --count=15 "[a] -> a"
```

I am in the root directory of my Yesod project - the main reason I installed it was to get help with Yesod functions - but when I try to find a function from Yesod like `addHeader`, it doesn't recognize a type defined on Yesod:

```
:t addHeader
addHeader :: MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()
:!hoogle --count=15 "MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()"
Warning: Unknown class MonadHandler
.
.
.
```

How can I setup hoogle to work beautifully with Yesod and also this very project I am working on, so that hoogle would bring my own functions and Yesod ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to first get Hoogle to create you a yesod-core database:

```
λ> :!hoogle data yesod-core
0 warnings, saved to .warnings
Data generation complete
```

Then it just works!

```
λ> :!hoogle "+yesod-core MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()"
Yesod.Core.Handler addHeader :: MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()
Yesod.Core.Handler deleteCookie :: MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()
Yesod.Core.Handler setHeader :: MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()
Yesod.Core.Handler setSession :: MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()
Yesod.Core.Widget toWidgetMedia :: (ToWidgetMedia site a, MonadWidget m, HandlerSite m ~ site) => Text -> a -> m ()
Yesod.Core.Json (.=) :: KeyValue kv => forall v. ToJSON v => Text -> v -> kv
```

Yuck, the `+yesod-core` tag isn't great. Fortunately, we can [combine our Hoogle databases into one big one](http://newartisans.com/2012/09/running-a-fully-local-hoogle/):

```
$ cd ~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-5.8/7.10.3/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.3/hoogle-4.2.43/databases 
$ mv default.hoo{,-prev}
$ hoogle combine *.hoo
```

(Your databases path will vary depending on whether you `stack install`ed or `cabal install`ed.)

```
λ> :!hoogle "addHeader"
Yesod.Core.Handler addHeader :: MonadHandler m => Text -> Text -> m ()
Network.CGI.Monad cgiAddHeader :: MonadCGI m => HeaderName -> String -> m ()
```

Way better than Google.

Comment: Could you explain your `mv` command? `mv default.hoo{,-prev}`

Comment: it's a shell expansion! a{foo,bar} = afoo aba